# cisco ios - syslog version

Tags: cisco, syslog, ios

I am writing small article on Syslog and I was wondering, if there is any resource that tells me what version of Syslog is supported in what ios version?

By Syslog version I mean rfc 3164/rfc 5424/some custom 'Syslog' protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support is mixed. Some devices support both, some only one and some again, neither (IOS-XR, which is a bit short-sided on their part). It is really up to the business units (sadly).

That being said, I find that 90% of the customers and vendors out there still use [RFC 3164](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3164). [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) might be considered "better" since it makes events easier to parse on the receiving end, but for some reason, the industry just hasn't really adopted it.

I published a paper on Cisco.com a little while back on syslog management which may help you out: [Building Scalable Syslog Management Solutions](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/technologies/collateral/tk869/tk769/white_paper_c11-557812.html)

Comment: No problem. if you need someone to proof your paper, I'd be happy to take a look when you're finished :-)